# WPF Window Visual Effect

Tags: c#, wpf

new to wpf want to know how to achieve the following;

For simplicity sake; I have a window, split into two rows via some container(s). I want to place a button in the top row (login) which on clicking the button, make it disappear and replace it with a User control.

I can hide the button through Visibility="Collapse", however my User Control is being clipped off by the bounds of the container.

How do I make the User Control overlap the container?

Here's an example of what I'm getting -

```
<DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Height="100" DockPanel.Dock="Top">

            <Button Content="Login"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Width="100"
                    Height="50"/>

            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="This is the big UserControl which is cut off by the bounds of the stack panel"
                           FontSize="20"
                           Width="200"
                           Height="200"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
```

Where TextBlock is replaced by a User Control register form, with labels and textboxes and a signup button.

As you can see the text is clipped by the bounds of the stackpanel like the user control would be, I want it to overlap keeping the stackpanel bounds the same, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue.

Comment: hope my edits helped :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button on top of UserControl you could do something like this -

```
<Grid Margin="2">
  <userControl1></userControl1>
  <Button/>
</Grid>
```

You can control what is visible and what isn't via Visibility property like you mentioned.

Comment: Okay. Is your problem solved yet? Based on your xaml it seems like you need to put your Stackpanel inside a ScrollViewer because your usercontrol is big.

Comment: I could do that, but I wanted to know if it was possible to make it extend outside the bounds of the parent Stackpanel bounds.

I tried using grid, and row span, almost worked but I got the below content squashed and a white background covering most of the screen due to Row2.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses a ToggleButton so the button doesn't disappear and you can toggle the visibility of the user control.

First, create a view

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2v" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ToggleButton Grid.Row="0"  IsChecked="{Binding IsButtonVisible, Mode=TwoWay}">Click Me</ToggleButton>

    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding IsButtonVisible, Converter={StaticResource b2v}}">
        <ListBox.Items>
            <ListBoxItem>London</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>New York</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Paris</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Create ViewModel

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    private bool _isButtonVisible = true;

    public bool IsButtonVisible
    {
        get { return _isButtonVisible; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _isButtonVisible) return;
            _isButtonVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    }
```

Load the ViewModel into the View's DataContext in the view constructor so that the bindings work.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
    }
```

That should work.

The toggle button changes the value of the IsButtonVisible property, which controls the visibility of the list box.

Comment: Setting visibility isn't what I'm trying to do, I hope the changes made to the question help clear things up, thank you for trying to help regardless :)